# C++ determine if templated variable is a class or just a built in type?

Tags: c++, templates, memory

**The Problem:**
I'm trying to explicitly call a destructor, however

```
int a;
class b;
b.~class(); // This works.
a.~int();   // This doesn't.
```

My code is templated, so I need a way to find out if they are giving my base types or not.

Example:

```
if(!basetype<Class>())
{
    classInst.~Class();
}
```

**A possible solution:**
I could partially template the base types so it didn't call the destructor, I am just looking for a simpler way. Maybe c++ has a built in operator for this I don't know lol.

PS: I love you.

**My Code:**

```
template<typename DestroyClass>
void HeapAllocator::destroy(HeapPointer<DestroyClass>& object)
{
    //object->DestroyClass::~DestroyClass();

    // Maintaining linked list references
    HeapPointer<EMPTY>* prevIndex = (HeapPointer<EMPTY>*)object.prev;
    HeapPointer<EMPTY>* nextIndex = (HeapPointer<EMPTY>*)object.next;
    if(prevIndex != 0)
        prevIndex->next = (U8*)nextIndex;
    else
        indexerStart = (U8*)nextIndex;  
    if(nextIndex != 0)
        nextIndex->prev = (U8*)prevIndex;
    else{
        indexerEnd = (U8*)prevIndex;
        if(prevIndex != 0)
            allocatorTop = prevIndex->end;
        else
            allocatorTop = heapBottom;
    }


    // Nullifying object so it can be overwritten
    object.start = 0;
    object.end = 0;
    object.alignment = 0;
    object.prev = 0;
    object.next = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ has a special rule that calling the destructor of a template parameter type in a template will work even for built-in types. This rule is to make writing templates easier. So while `int x; x.~int()` won't compile, `T t; t.~T()` in a template where `T = int` will compile and do nothing.

Comment: LOL, I would of found that out if i wasn't so dumb. I was trying to destruct after an overloaded operator that was screwing me up. StackOverflow is the best.

Comment: Not that I doubt you or anything, but where in the standard is this rule documented?